# How can I serve a particular file for root url in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I need to serve file from my filesystem for `GET /` request. I tried the following:

```
location = / {
  index page2257160.html;
  root /var/www/site/;
}
```

The rest of requests are proxied to backend:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:1234;
}
```

But when I do the request, instead of serving the file from filesystem, nginx asks backend about `/page2257160.html`, backend returns 404, nginx sends this 404 back to client.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` directive performs an internal redirect, so you will need a second location to match the rewritten URI. For example:

```
root /var/www/site/;
location = / {
    index page2257160.html;
}
location = /page2257160.html {
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

---

You can achieve the same thing with one `location` block and a `try_files` directive. For example:

```
location = / {
    root /var/www/site/;
    try_files /page2257160.html =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.